# Как определить свайп

Tags: java, android

Я в андроид новичок. В моем приложении нужно реализовать закрытие активити свайпом(слева направо). Проблема в том, что я еще не работал со свайпом. Поэтому и вопрос такой: "Как определить свайп?"
 Спасибо!

Comment: В чем имено проблема? Вы не можете определить свайп, или закрыть `Activity`?

Comment: Я еще только учусь разрабатывать под данную платформу, поэтому со свайпом еще не работал

Comment: Не знаю, какой именно свайп имелся ввиду, но попробуйте [это](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1364).

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы он соответствовал вашей проблеме - `Как определить свайп`

Comment: Я отвечал с хорошим примером на аналогичный вопрос.